# How to use a separate repo for calculations used by backend?

Tags: node.js, git, vue.js, express, organization

I have a web app built with Vue.js that needs to obtain the result of an expensive process from the backend server. Specifically, I would like the backend API endpoint to invoke a separate script on the server to perform the calculation. However the scripts needed are managed in a separate git repo, and I want to keep it that way.

What is the best way for me to organize my project so that I can manage the backend scripts separately, but I can still use them in my server? An ideal solution would allow me to keep the scripts up to date easily, and would allow the (Node) server to easily invoke them from a known directory.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. How is it being a separate repository a problem of deployment? Just put them somewhere on your server, then call them (you know where they are stored, because you put them there).

Comment: "from a known directory" - the directory is node_modules. This is what Node modules are for

Comment: I know of no way to manage two separate Git repositories with some files in common that is easy. Use a package manager?